# Docker protractor run ends with E/launcher - Process exited with error code 135

Tags: docker, docker-compose, protractor, devops, selenium-grid

community,
I'm stuck with the running of protractor tests in docker. Please help me to resolve my problem. Thanks

Here is what I'm trying to do.

1. I'm packing Angular application with protractor e2e tests

```
baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://172.18.0.2:4444/wd/hub/',
```

to a docker image with help of Docker file

```
FROM node:12.8.1-alpine as build-step
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g protractor@5.4.2
RUN apk add openjdk8
ENV PATH $PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin
COPY . .
EXPOSE 4200 4444
CMD npm start
```

2. I'm running docker-compose contains running of selenium grid containers(hub and chrome) and dockerfile above

```
version: "3"
services:
  hub:
    container_name: hub
    image: selenium/hub:3.141.59
    privileged: true
    ports: 
      - 4444:4444
    environment:
      - GRID_BROWSER_TIMEOUT=240000
      - GRID_TIMEOUT=240000
  chrome:
    container_name: node-chrome
    image: selenium/node-chrome:3.141.59
    privileged: true
    shm_size: 256M
    depends_on:
      - hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=hub
      - no_proxy=localhost
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=hub
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
  testapp:
    container_name: testapp
    build: .
    image: dneprokos/testapp
    ports:               
      - "4200:4200"
    depends_on:             
      - chrome
      - hub
```

3. I'm trying to execute protractor conf file command in order to run e2e tests. (seleniumAddress: 'http://172.18.0.2:4444/wd/hub/')

```
docker container exec -it testapp sh // to attach
protractor ./e2e/protractor.conf.js // to run tests
```

Notes:

First I tried to run tests inside of the container with localhost, but than realized it contains another host inside of the container. But it hasn't resolved the problem even when I've changed the host.

Also, I tried do not run grid containers, but using "webdriver-manager update" and "webdriver-manager start" commands. Starting works fine, but the same problem happens during tests start.

As you may seem I've exposed ports, so I can easily check it works locally for both selenium grid and test application. 
Only one thing, if I'm trying to connect locally to "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/" it shows me the following exception:

"sessionId": null,
  "status": 13,
  "value": {
    "class": "org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException",
    "error": "unknown error",
    "message": "Session [(null externalkey)] not available and is not among the last 1000 terminated sessions.\nActive sessions are[]",

**Expected Result**: Test run should be started

**Actual Result**:

```
[17:44:34] E/launcher - Error code: 135
[17:44:34] E/launcher - Error message: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.2:4444
[17:44:34] E/launcher - Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.2:4444
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:238:15)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:203:13)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:399:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:203:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
```

Comment: Use the container names in the URL instead. For my setup, when I want the tests to use the hub I use `seleniumAddress: 'http://hub:4444/wd/hub'` and to run tests against `testapp` I would use `--baseUrl=http://testapp:4200`

Comment: Also, once you spin up your environment, connect to the hub and chrome node to make sure everything is ready. You should see some messages about the node attempting to register and then another one when it has successfully registered with the hub. Something may be going wrong there that is causing it to fail. `docker logs hub` and `docker logs node-chrome` should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've added container names as URLs and it's started to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a comment I've resolved my problem. Just need to use containers name for application base URL and Selenium Hub URL in protractor.conf, like this

### 'http://hub:4444/wd/hub'

### 'baseUrl=http://testapp:4200'

Also, I found I need to start an angular application with a following command "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check". In another case, there will be some troubles with opening application in the container.